# how to call a storyboard scene conditionally from a button

Tags: iphone, uibutton, storyboard

I have an application who's first scene is a login screen. On pressing the login button, if the username and password are correct, the next scene should get called. Otherwise an alert is shown. But I am unable to figure out how to get the next scene conditionally.

```
if ([jsonDict valueForKey:@"success"] && [jsonDict valueForKey:@"redirect"]) {

                    NSLog(@"%@", [jsonDict valueForKey:@"success"]);
                    NSLog(@"%@", [jsonDict valueForKey:@"redirect"]);
                    NSString *redirect = [jsonDict valueForKey:@"redirect"];
                    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"next" sender:self];
                }
                else {
                    NSArray *jsonArray = [jsonDict valueForKey:@"errors"];
                    NSString *err = [jsonArray objectAtIndex:0];
                    NSLog(@"%@", err);
                    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Invalid Credentials!" message:err delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                    [alert show];
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set up a Segue to the next viewcontroller in your storyboard and give that segue a unique identifier. Then, if username and password are ok, just call

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourSegueIdentifier" sender:self];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
- (void)validateLogin{
//code to check username and password are correct
if(correct){
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SignInToNextScreen" sender:self];
}else{
 UIAlertView *myalert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Login Failed" message:@"Invalid Username/Password" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];   
   }
 }
```

//**SignInToNextScreen** is a segue identifier for manually triggered segue.

Please see the attached screen shot
[image]

Comment: Sorry, I am new to storyboards. Can u please guide me on how to set the segue identifier?

Comment: @user2160539, one min.. I will post u a video

Comment: Watch this video...YOu will know how to configure segue manually.....http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CwHvPRhPXt8&feature=youtube_gdata_player

Comment: I have done this. But now I am facing another problem. The segue gets called even when the login condition is not satisfied. Below is my code.

Comment: @user2160539, paste code in your question...Segue should give to the uiviewcontroller but not for directly as a button action

Comment: I have copied the code in my question. else condition is satisfied in case of invalid login. but the next view still gets called

Comment: @user2160539, code seems to be correct, check once your IBAction for that button. Don't select button and drag segue to next screen. Select Entire signIn screen and drag segue to next screen as I showed in video

Comment: @user2160539,Good to Hear...If my answer useful..accept it...So, that it will help to others